# MySQL query working only on some versions

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
     (
       SELECT
         DATEDIFF( birthdate,  CONCAT(YEAR(birthdate), '/1/1') ) AS Distance,
         DATEDIFF( CURDATE(), CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '/1/1')) AS TodaysDistance,
         db.Contact.*
       FROM
         db.Contact
       WHERE
         db.Contact.id IN (
           SELECT
             db.addressbook.contactid
           FROM
             db.addressbook
           WHERE
             db.addressbook.ownerid = 9
       )
       ) AS DistanceTable
   )
   WHERE
     ABS(DistanceTable.Distance - DistanceTable.TodaysDistance) <= 7
   ORDER BY
     ABS(DistanceTable.Distance - DistanceTable.TodaysDistance)
   LIMIT 0, 10;
```

It loads the birthdays of my contact list table and shows me the next 10 upcoming birthdays on my contact list. My development server is MySQL 5.0.51a and the production server is 5.1.57, is there any chance that is a version problem?

**EDIT** I did simulated the exact same environment on my local PC (same PHP version, same MySQL version and even installed all on my Virtual Machine running Debian Lenny like the server and I keep getting the same problem on the server, while on the local machine works like a charm)

Another thing I did was testing the query on the server's PhpMyAdmin tool and it works ok there, so Im guessing it's a problem with the credentials of the PHP process, any thoughts?

Comment: Is there an error?  What is it doing on the developpment server that it is not doing on the production server?

Comment: yes on the server i have a "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142"

Comment: Seeing as the statement runs on your development server I'd say this is an access violation and not a syntax error.  Was there anything else on the tail end of the error message?

Comment: First thing i would try is to test if all math and date functions like ABS and DATEDIFF you are using are supported in the production environment in simple isolated queries. You never know what those webhosters consider useless or too expensive performance wise and disallow. Then you can move on to simplifying the joins until it starts working again. I don't think you have something in there that is not generally supported by mysql 5.1 itself, seems more like a configuration issue on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See MySQL error codes here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html

Make sure that you have the same access permissions on both your dev and production servers. Your error code corresponds to:

```
%s command denied to user '%s'@'%s' for table '%s'
```